# Unable to install yarn on windows 10

Tags: node.js, installation, npm-install, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I installed node v16.13.0, npm v8.1.0 java version 1.8.0_211 and I thought I also have installed yarn, but trying to install expo using yarn global add expo-cli I get:

```
yarn : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.ps1 is not
digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and
setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ yarn global add expo-cli
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Then I tried to install yarn again, but now I am 100% unable to get it:

```
PS C:\Users\user> npm install -g yarn

changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

but running yarn --version I get the same error as before:

```
yarn : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.ps1 is not
digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and
setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ yarn --version
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: Are you running it on powershell? try running it on command prompt

Comment: By cmd it showed the version that is installed (C:\Users\spike>yarn --version 1.22.15), why can't I get it from powershell?
But even using cmd or whatever else, I was unable of using yarn, it was my system environment that had to be changed in the path

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Execute:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend this approach as the answer by Saber works (and is safer).

Answer (score 6):

I suggest not changing your system policy.

Instead, follow this:

Remove yarn.ps1 from the directory C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\ then try clearing the npm cache at C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\

Comment: I have no npm-cache folder

Comment: I feel like this is the correct answer. Changing security policies for a single issue is a scary thing, and following these steps corrected the issue for me.

Comment: In my case the file to remove was C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.ps1. After removing it (i renamed it), yarn command works.

Comment: I had nvm so it was in C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.2\

Answer (score 1):

Under your npm install directory, rename `yarn.ps1` to `yarn_disabled.ps1`. Now whenever you call `yarn`, the system will fallback to `yarn.CMD` which does not have the concept of digital signatures unlike PowerShell.

This is recommended over changing execution policy.